# Relative placement of node on edge with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How do I place a node relative to an edge? It's easy with lines using the `--` operator, is there a way to achieve the same on an edge?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5cm]
    \node(A){A};
    \node[right of=A](B){B};
    \node[below of=A, node distance=2cm](C){C};
    \node[right of=C](D){D};

    \draw (A) -- (B) node[midway, above]{this works};
    \draw (C) edge[out=-90, in=-90] (D) node[midway, below]{this not};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `\draw[out=-90, in=-90] (C) to node[below]{this not} (D);` what you want?

Comment: Yes, it is! I've been working on this for days. Thanks! Do you mind posting this as answer? I am currently not allowed to answer my own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your MWE will work as intended if you specify the node before the end of the edge. This also works with a `to` path operation (Manual section: `The To Path Operation`) instead of `edge`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5cm]
    \node(A){A};
    \node[right of=A](B){B};
    \node[below of=A, node distance=2cm](C){C};
    \node[right of=C](D){D};

    \draw (A) -- (B) node[midway, above]{this works};
    \draw (C) edge[bend right] node[below]{and this works} (D);
    \draw[out=-90, in=-90] (C) to node[below]{this also works} (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For me it also works with `edge` instead of `to`. It seems the problem was the parameter order (use `node` before `to` / `edge`, not after).